# Breaking down a list in a string whilst acknowledging empty strings

Tags: regex, lua

I implemented the following expression to my script to breakdown a list which is received as a string:

```
result = "65,TESTDB,;65,TESTDB2,"

local breakDown={}
for str in result:gmatch("([^,;]+)") do table.insert(breakDown, str) end

 print(breakDown[1])
 print(breakDown[4])
```

However, in the example above two of the fields are entered blank (position 3 and 6).

Essentially I would like `breakDown[4]` to print `65`, but it would currently print `TESTDB2`.

I know I could split into two lists by the `;` and then select the first number in each and that does work for my application.

I was just wondering if there is a neater way to do it, especially if there were a multitude of sets of lists (broken up by `;`)?

Comment: `[^,;]+` matches multiple `,` or `;` in a row. Just get rid of the `+` from the regexp

Comment: `for str in (";"..result):gmatch"[,;]([^,;]*)" do `

Comment: @Egor your solution worked, I'd be happy to green tick it if you post as an answer with a brief explaination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Egor for the following answer:

```
for str in (";"..result):gmatch"[,;]([^,;]*)" do
```